# Woocommerce when deleting a product, automatically also delete the product gallery and product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying the following:

when a product page gets deleted (permanently), it should also delete the:
product gallery and product image which are attached to the post.

I tried the solution i found on:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109793/delete-associated-media-upon-page-deletion

But it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 10):

Although this is an old question, I will leave it here in case someone will be looking for it in the future.

Since you want to delete product images, you may try these neat and handy woocommerce functions to get attachments ids.

Something like this:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'delete_product_images', 10, 1 );

function delete_product_images( $post_id )
{
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    if ( !$product ) {
        return;
    }

    $featured_image_id = $product->get_image_id();
    $image_galleries_id = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

    if( !empty( $featured_image_id ) ) {
        wp_delete_post( $featured_image_id );
    }

    if( !empty( $image_galleries_id ) ) {
        foreach( $image_galleries_id as $single_image_id ) {
            wp_delete_post( $single_image_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: I'm here from the future wanted to say THANK YOU!! Adding this code in `wp-includes/functions.php` did the trick!!

Comment: DO NOT do what @Mahmoud Eidarous did. NEVER edit core WordPress files.

Comment: well @Spyros .. you could at least suggest a better answer.

Comment: @MahmoudEidarous you are right. DO NOT do what Mahmoud suggests. Never edit core WordPress files. If you want to add custom code, then add it to your custom theme, child theme, or a custom plugin.

Comment: @Spyros is absolutely right, editing core WP files is not the way to go. To safely and correctly implement functionality like this, the "easiest" way is to add the code to your child theme's functions.php file. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action("before_delete_post","wdm_delete_post_images",10,1);

function wdm_delete_post_images($post_id)
{
 global $wpdb;
          $args = array(
                'post_parent' => $post_id,
                'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'any' 
        ); 
        $childrens = get_children( $args);
        if($childrens):
            foreach($childrens as $attachment):   
             wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true ); 
             $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE post_id = ".$attachment->ID);
             wp_delete_post($attachment->ID,true ); 
            endforeach;

        endif;
}
```

Comment: If you're giving an answer in the form of a code, try to explain it and not to just give the code like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
add_action('after_delete_post','wdm_delete_post_images',10,1);

function wdm_delete_post_images($post_id)
{
   $featured_image_id = get_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',true);

   $image_galleries_id = get_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery',true);

   if(!empty($featured_image_id))
   {
     wp_delete_post($featured_image_id);
   }

  if(!empty($image_galleries_id))
  {
    $image_galleries_array = split(',',$image_galleries_id);

    foreach($image_galleries_array as $single_image_id)
    {
        wp_delete_post($single_image_id);
    }
  }
}
```

This will delete images when product is permanently deleted.

Comment: He specified that he only wanted this for products, so I added a check for product post type.

Comment: It didnt work for me yet, I looked in to the database and replaced "_thumbnail_id" with "_wp_attached_file" can you tell me what should go in the $key or "key"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Login to Your PhpMyAdmin | If you have more than one database, make sure you click on the correct database. If you’re not sure because you have more than one WordPress installation on the same domain, open a table and look for “wp_options”, you’ll be able to see the URL of the website you’re making changes to.

Step 2: Run the SQL Statement ==> in WP_POST

If you are on the correct database, click on the SQL tab on the top right. It might be empty or have an SQL statement there from a previous command.

```
DELETE relations.*, taxes.*, terms.*
FROM wp_term_relationships AS relations
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxes
ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms
ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id
WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product');

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try it one time not need any more code for delete product.**
>   **You can add this code in one new file and place in root directory of wordpress.**

```
include('wp-load.php');
    function delete_post($sku)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $result_post = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',".$sku.", '%')" );
            for($q=0;$q<count($result_post);$q++)
            {
                wp_delete_post($result_post[$q]->ID,true); // wp_delete_post full product delete with its all images
            }
    }

    delete_post($sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this code and it works.  But I'm trying to add more code to create a function that when I delete a product definitively, this in addition to being deleted from the wordpress "media" folder, is deleted from another folder in my ftp, where the same images are present with the same names.  so I simply need to know the name of the file, delete it from the "media" folder and then delete it from another folder where there is a copy of that file.  How can I do?

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'delete_product_images', 10, 1 );

function delete_product_images( $post_id )
{
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

if ( !$product ) {
    return;
}

$featured_image_id = $product->get_image_id();
$image_galleries_id = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if( !empty( $featured_image_id ) ) {
    wp_delete_post( $featured_image_id );
}

if( !empty( $image_galleries_id ) ) {
    foreach( $image_galleries_id as $single_image_id ) {
        wp_delete_post( $single_image_id );
    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Automatically Delete Woocommerce Images After Deleting a Product

add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'delete_product_images', 10, 1 );

 

function delete_product_images( $post_id ) {

        // Check if user has the capability to delete products

        if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_products' ) ) {

            return;

        }

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

 

    if ( !$product ) {

        return;

    }

 

    $featured_image_id = $product->get_image_id();

    $image_galleries_id = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

 

    if( !empty( $featured_image_id ) ) {

        $is_featured_image_used = is_image_used( $featured_image_id, $post_id );

        if ( !$is_featured_image_used ) {

            wp_delete_attachment( $featured_image_id, true );

        }

    }

 

    if( !empty( $image_galleries_id ) ) {

        foreach( $image_galleries_id as $single_image_id ) {

            $is_image_used = is_image_used( $single_image_id, $post_id );

            if ( !$is_image_used ) {

                wp_delete_attachment( $single_image_id, true );

            }

        }

    }

}

 

function is_image_used( $image_id, $current_product_id ) {

    $query = new WP_Query( array(

        'post_type' => 'product',

        'post_status' => 'publish',

        'meta_query' => array(

            'relation' => 'OR',

            array(

                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',

                'value' => $image_id,

                'compare' => '='

            ),

            array(

                'key' => '_product_image_gallery',

                'value' => '"'.$image_id.'"',

                'compare' => 'LIKE'

            )

        ),

        'post__not_in' => array( $current_product_id ),

        'fields' => 'ids',

        'posts_per_page' => -1

    ) );

 

    return ( $query->have_posts() );

}
```